# How can I count the child elements in between a class, using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there any methode to count the elements between a class: pic_1. the output should be 3 and 2, because there are 3 tr td elements and then again after the class 2.

all the td tags except tags containing picture are display:none as default. I want, if i click on the first picture, it should show the first 3 tds. (hallo 1, hallo 2, hallo 3) and if i click on picture 2. it should show me (hallo 1, hallo 2) for that i can work with toogle but how can i count, how many elements are under class: pic_1 till next pic.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="" class="Pic_1">Picture1</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hallo 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hallo 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hallo 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="" class="Pic_2">Picture2</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hallo 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hallo 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The idea here is you show what you've tried, explain what's not working, then we help. Your question currently asks someone to do the work for you.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: all the td tags except tags containing picture are display:none as default. I want, if i click on the first picture, it should show the first 3 tds. (hallo 1, hallo 2, hallo 3) and if i click on picture 2. it should show me (hallo 1, hallo 2).

Comment: Now you just repeated what you _want_, you were asked to tell/show us what you have _tried_ so far. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The elements you want to show are not “between” those other elements with the classes, not in a DOM sense. It’s not impossible to achieve what you want - but this HTML structure is really not too well suited for it to begin with. Question would be whether this should be a table in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use classes to show/hide the relative elements to a particular element. Let's say give hello 1/2/3 the class as `'Pic_1_relatives'` and for hello 1/2 the class as `'Pic_2_relatives'`

Now on Click of Pic_1 just show the 'Pic_1_relatives' -> display: block and 'Pic_2_relatives' -> display: none; and Do same on click of 'Pic_2_relatives'